# Что вызывается первым Filter or Middleware in pipeline? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, filter, middleware

Проходила собеседование и не ответилана вопрос: "что вызывается первым фильр или по промежуточного слоя"?

Нашла несколько статей со сравнением, но в одной из них говорится, что фильтры отрабатывают после мидлварки; а в другой, что могут как до, так и после.

Может кто-нибудь уточнить этот момент?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Они скорее всего хотели узнать что Middleware идут раньше Endpoint Filter

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0 Filters in ASP.NET Core allow code to be run before or after specific stages in the request processing pipeline...Разве это не означает что может быть перед

Comment: Да но мидлевары идут раньше. Тут речь идет о том что фильтры могут идти раньше или позже специфичных стадий

Comment: спасибо.очень помог))